# Arabic text in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, arabic-support

i have array of objects like this

```
"sub-specialty" : [
        {
          "id" : 1,
          "title" : "Adult Physiotherapy",
          "ar_title" : "علاج طبيعي بالغين",
          "name" : "علاج طبيعي بالغين"
        },
        {
          "id" : 2,
          "title" : "Pediatric Physiotherapy",
          "ar_title" : "علاج طبيعي اطفال",
          "name" : "علاج طبيعي اطفال"
        },
        {
          "id" : 3,
          "title" : "Sport Injuries",
          "ar_title" : "اصابات ملاعب",
          "name" : "اصابات ملاعب"
        },
        {
          "id" : 4,
          "title" : "Rehabilitation",
          "ar_title" : "تأهيل",
          "name" : "تأهيل"
        }
      ]
```

when i use map to grab name only like this

```
let sub = sub-specialty.map({($0.name ?? "")}).joined(separator: ", ") ?? ""
```

i got rubbish characters or text is flipped   please see the attached image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnXNd.jpg)

Comment: Try putting the text in a `UILabel` or something. Maybe the Xcode console is confused.

Comment: @Sweeper i already put it on label but i get the same characters on label

Comment: Show your code for parsing the json.

Comment: Can you please check with print(String(describing: arabic text))

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text as String and set wherever you want to set. It will work fine. I have worked with multi languages and this work for me.

Comment: I am facing an issue with arabic. when I change the app locale from settings half of text are not changed I have checked the keys are correct because when I change the language to Spanish all text are appear perfectively.